# Jenkins github pull request builder picks wrong commit

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am using Jenkins with the plugin [GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin). I then have set up webhooks from GitHub to trigger a build in jenkins when a new Pull Request is opened or committed to.

I configured the GHPRB plugin with the Jenkins DSL:

```
job("name") {
    properties {
        githubProjectUrl("https://github.com/org/${repo}")
    }
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                name("origin")
                url("git@github.com:org/${repo}.git")
                credentials("jenkins-ssh-keyid")
            }
            branch("**")
            extensions {
                gitTagMessageExtension()
            }
        }
    }
    triggers {
        githubPullRequest{
            admins(["github-username"])
            orgWhitelist('org-name')
            cron("")
            triggerPhrase("build")
            extensions {
                commitStatus {
                    context("unittest")
                }
            }
           useGitHubHooks()
       }
    }
    steps {
        shell("./run-unittests");
    }
}
```

The problem I am experiences is that sometimes Jenkins will get confused and pick the wrong commit to build on.

When that happens, the jenkins output looks like this:

```
GitHub pull request #9 of commit 126434b, no merge conflicts.
Setting status of 126434b to PENDING with url http://jenkins/job/unittest/26/ and message: 'Build started sha1 is merged.'
Using context: unittest
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:org/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:org/repo.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:org/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-branch-0
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-branch-1
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-branch-2
Seen 3 remote branches
Checking out Revision 1995d66 (origin/master)
```

Here, Jenkins goes from using the tip of the feature branch (`126434b`) to using the tip of master (`1995d66`) instead.

```
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1995d66
 > git rev-list ba7ec55 # timeout=10
 > git describe --tags 126434b # timeout=10
Tag information could not be determined for this revision; no git tag info will be exported
```

Notice that when [Git Tag Message Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Tag+Message+Plugin) runs `git describe` to check for tag information, it is using the commit id for the feature branch.

Jenkins then goes on with the job, working on the master tip (`1995d66`), instead of the feature branch tip (`126434b`) as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `branch` specification and `refspec`. Changing the `scm.git` section of job to this solved the problem of Jenkins checking out the wrong commit:

```
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            name("origin")
            url("git@github.com:org/${repo}.git")
            credentials("jenkins-ssh-keyid")
            refspec('+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*')
            }
            branch('${ghprbActualCommit}')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the docs specify that the refspec needs to be that string - however, they also suggest setting branch to `${sha1}`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this issue for the same reasons we did!

It can happen if your cache is corrupt.  Check for a "cache" folder under your Jenkins one, and delete all of the git folders inside of it.  (Shut down Jenkins first, of course).